# Create View in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following database tables:

1. Table Name "hotels" Column Names: "id", "hotel",
2. Table Name "hotel_sites" Column Names: "id", "hotel_id", "site_id"
3. Table Name "reviews" Column Names: "id", "hotel_site_id", "hotel_id", "site_id", "review_date", "review_content"
4. Table Name "sites" Column names: "id", "site"

What I want to do is create a view that shows me the actual hotel names, rather than the IDs in one view, almost as if it was a spreadsheet.

So I want:

hotel (Column 1) site (Column 2) review_content (Column 3) review_date (Column 4)

This would then give me (for example):

1. hotel = Hilton Las Vegas
2. site = www.hotel-reviews.com
3. review_content = We loved our stay!
4. review_date = 28/12/2013

At the moment all I can see is reviews with reference IDs which visually don't show me the name of the actual sites. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT

h.hotel,
s.site,
r.review_content,
r.review_date

FROM
hotels AS h
LEFT JOIN hotel_sites AS hs ON (hs.hotel_id = h.id)
LEFT JOIN sites AS s ON (s.id = hs.site_id)
LEFT JOIN reviews AS r ON (r.hotel_site_id = hs.id)
```

Comment: Hi @verhie - this works fine, thank you very much indeed. I have been looking at some tutorials but couldn't seem to do this. Much appreciated.

Comment: Always look for joins. MySQL was born for that!

Comment: I am a mere amateur @verhie, no idea what they are, but will take a look. Thanks again!